# JHipster on Docker issue

Tags: docker, jhipster

Trying to start JHipster Docker container (as per instruction [here](https://jhipster.github.io/installation/)) `docker run --name jhipster -v <mypath>:/home/jhipster/app -v <mypath>:/home/jhipster/.m2 -p 8080:8080 -p 9000:9000 -p 3001:3001 -d -t jhipster/jhipster`. I see this error `New state of 'nil' is invalid.` This is with Docker `17.03.0-ce` on Windows. Any pointers ?

Comment: Hi Abhishek, I am also facing the same issue. Did you resolved it?

Comment: No. Haven't been able to resolve it

Comment: Please check whether this link 
which explains about the error helps.
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/22345

Comment: You can run this docker compose app instead, this makes your job simple. Use command "$./mvnw package -Pprod dockerfile:build" to build docker file and follow instructions from  "http://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/"